# c# winforms реализация программы автономного работающей базы данных

Tags: c#, winforms

хочу создать программу с базы данных  на c# winform-e, чтобы программа автономно ( без сервера ) добавляла и удаляла данные, как я могу реализовать такой проект , подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте SQLite.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/

Comment: Как альтернатива SQLite есть ещё Firebird и стандартная реализация от мелкософтов, при которой файл базы создаётся локально.